# Rails 4.2 - Passing variable to .(params[:id]) Possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, parameter-passing

I have a variable @category in my controller and I want to pass another variable @source to it. 
eg. @category = Category.find(params[:id=>@source])
Is this possible?

Inside my controller:

```
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @source = @article.category_id
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

My view:

```
<%= link_to @category, category_path(:id=>@source) %>
```

I've tinkered around with various combos and approaches but none have worked.
 @article belongs to a category and is associated via .category_id. 
@category has a separate model and I want to give @category.find(params[:id]) its id via @article.category_id.

How could I go about doing this?

(This is to implement into a navigational tree/breadcrumbs)

Comment: Have you tried just `<%= link_to @category, category_path(@source) %>` ?  That should get the link to work, but you probably want to access an attribute of @category as the first argument to link_to ? Like `<%= link_to @category.name, category_path(@source) %>` ?

Comment: Helios I have tried that but the id does not get passed to the controller. You are right about the attribute, I am using @category.title.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to find category via article, then you can do:

```
def show
  @article =  Article.find(params[:id])
  @category = @article.category
end
```

as there is an association in **Article** model.

Now In view, you can use:

```
<%= link_to @category.name, category_path(@category) %>
```

Comment: First argument to `link_to` should be String.  `= link_to @category.name, category_path(@category)` or just `= link_to @category.name, @category`

Comment: This almost works, but the id cannot be passed (even if I try category_path(:id=>@ category.id). It seems like @ category cannot access the category attributes because when I try link_to @ category.title, it throws a nomethoderror

Comment: @nvrpicurnose. Did you have a space in between `@ category` ?  And does category have a title attribute?

Comment: no there was no space in @ category, I just did that because stackoverflow thought I was referencing a user. yes category does have a title attribute.